# ROR: NOT EQUAL condition between two table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three tables: User, User_Interest, and Interest

How could I get the interest names that one of the users doesn't have?

(I have already set up the model for all of them.)

Thanks for your kindly help.

Comment: Please look at the Rails Guides on model associations:
Rails 3: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html
Rails 2.3.x: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make this a class method on User, or an instance method on a particular user. For the class method, try this:

```
def self.missing_interests(user)
    difference = Interest.all - user.interests
    difference.map { |d| d.name }
end
```

and call it with `User.missing_interests(some_user)`. For instance, try

```
def missing_interests
    difference = Interest.all - interests
    difference.map { |d| d.name }
end
```

and call with `missing = some_user.missing_interests`.

That should return an array with the names of all interests not included in the `interests` association for user.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I change a little bit. I use "@missing_interests = Interest.all - User.find(session[:uid]).interests" in the controller.